# iPhone Simulator build error on iPad and works fine on iPhone Simulator and iPhone Device

Tags: iphone

I am having a hard time figuring out this problem. My app has iAds enabled and it works on iPhone (device) and iPhone (simulator) 4.1. I know version 3.2 (iPad) does not support ads. So, I did a weak link to the iad library. In the build options => linking => other link tags I wrote iAd. After this I get a build error:

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/One2ThreePop.app/One2ThreePop normal i386
cd /Users/azamsharp/Documents/123Pop
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk -L/Users/azamsharp/Documents/123Pop/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/azamsharp/Documents/123Pop/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/azamsharp/Documents/123Pop/build/One2ThreePop.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/One2ThreePop.build/Objects-normal/i386/One2ThreePop.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 iAd -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenAL -lz -framework AVFoundation "-lcocos2d libraries" -weak_framework iAd -o /Users/azamsharp/Documents/123Pop/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/One2ThreePop.app/One2ThreePop

i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: iAd: No such file or directory
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you check at runtime for the existence of the iAd libraries before you call them, including loading a NIB with and iAd banner?  You need to bypass the iAd stuff on the iPad.

Comment: Do I have to do that? I thought weak linking will take care of this problem.